# How can i create liner loading in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in `javascript`,and want to implant the simple liner loading in my html page,for that purpose write this code:

```
<div id="Back" style="width:100%;background-color:#1D1F20;height:5px;opacity:0.3;">
        <div id="sample" style="width:0%;background-color:#0099DA;height:5px;">
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#sample").animate({ "width": "100%" });
        });
        function LoadComplete() {
            alert('Load Complete');
        }
        window.onload = LoadComplete();
    </script>
```

want to until the web site completely load,that loader show to user,after page complete load then that loader is close,how can i solve that problem?thanks all.

Comment: jquery. `.ready`  executes when "...Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.", check the documentation https://api.jquery.com/ready/ . `window.onload = LoadComplete();`should be `window.onload = LoadComplete;` check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload . You Problem is not clear. what do you want to achive? If the pages didn't finish loading it cannot display a loadingbar.

Comment: @winner_joiner thanks for pay attention to my problem,i want to have loader in my page

Answer (score 0):

1. load jquery library
2. place this right after #sample div into script

   $("#sample").animate({ "width": "100%" });

Reason why it doesn't work is that you run above function inside $(document).ready function that executes when the page has loaded.
So you wait for the page to load and then you run your loader. which doesn't make sense.